# matplotlib: print histogram based upon multi-dimensional dictionary data

Tags: python, matplotlib

it's my first time using python. I want to plot a histogram based on a simple data set stored in a dictionary as follows:

```
x = {'2010': [2,555,11], '2011': [1, 777, 12], ...}
```

as you can see, there would be three data values each bin.

It's easy to make a plot based on only one data, but how to handle this case?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `dict` is important `keyword` in `Python` so don't use it as a variable name. That is `d = dict()` generates a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

> n, bins, patches = pylab.hist(x, 10, normed=1, histtype='bar',
>   **stacked=True**)

Follow the example given in this [{matplotlib example page}](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html), it is very helpful.

[image]

---

**Simple Example:**

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
x = np.random.rand(100,3)
pl.hist(x,stacked=True)
pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: x=dict.values() doesn't work here. variable 'bins' give me [ 34.53  34.63  34.73  34.83  34.93  35.03  35.13  35.23  35.33  35.43
  35.53] for the one dataset '2010'.

Comment: according to the given example in the link `x` must be in the shape `(n,k)` in which n is the total case number say 1000 and k is the number of variables let say 3. Don't use `dict` as variable because it is keyword in Python, so you change it as `data = {'2010': [2,555,11], '2011': [1, 777, 12], ...}`, now `data.values()` will be a list `[[2,555,11],[1, 777, 12],...]`. Use `numpy.asarray` to make it as `(n,3)`. Should work.

Comment: I don't have a 'stack' option. Anyways. For my data [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
[35.03 2.05 32.98 8.25]] and p1.hist(x) I got http://goo.gl/eYNNl0

Comment: @JohnRumpel If you're using `matplotlib` as in your question title you can pass `stacked=True` to `pl.hist()`. Just follow the example given in my answer. Spend sometime reading some basic examples from matplotlib website, if you're **really** interested in learning `Python`.